# mule configuration for multiple client

Tags: mule

I am new to the mule configuration and my query is:

1. I have to accept the request from multiple client and make it as a generic response.xml. To make it as a generic xml i can do it.
2. The things which i am not aware of is, how to accept the generic response and how to pass it to the client specific processor? How to do the same in mule configuration file?
3. Do i need to add the multiple classes for multiple clients? I think YES

I need your help for #2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague and confusing so I'm going to try a catch-all answer.

Use a choice router to route the generic response to the specific client processor based on message properties or contents.

Documentation: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-Choice